# Weblogic 12c - characters unreadable during the installation

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to install weblogic 12c on a RHEL 7.4 and when I open the window to begin the installation, all the characters are unreadable.

[image: Weblogic installation window]

I can copy-past these characters into notepad and all characters are readable there.

Java version used: 1.7.0_79-b15

Comment: What do you mean with "unreadable" - invisible? mangled? Obfuscaded? Mixed up?

Comment: Appears only one special character, I attached a print-screen of the window in the post.

Comment: This question feels like it might do better on https://superuser.com/ or perhaps one of the other stackexchange sister sites than here.

Answer (score 0):

looks like character encoding issue to me..
have you checked the LANG environment variable to see the character encoding? 
If it's not UTF-8, set the variable for your current shell.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Set these variables and this issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an issue of compatibility with the **RHEL 7.4**

After created a new Virtual Machine with RHEL 6.* I was able to execute the jar properly and install the Weblogic 12c

Answer (score 0):

We also faced similar kind of issue.Try to install the package "xorg-x11-fonts-Type1" and try.

Comment: Try is not an answer it comes as comments